# How can I change my default inbox and sent folders in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have two parent folders:

**1. Outlook data**

```
Inbox
Sent
Deleted
```

**2. IP address**

```
Inbox
Sent
Deleted
```

Now my default Sent and Inbox folders are under the *IP Address* folder.

How can I change the default Sent and Inbox items to be under *Outlook data*?

Comment: In Outlook 2010, when I go to File > Account Settings > select the account & click on 'Change'. Click on 'More Settings' there is no 'Sent Items' tab.

Comment: I can't see the "Send Items tab" after clicking "More Settings...". There are only: General, Advanced, Security, Connection. (Outlook 2010).

Comment: My IMAP accounts have 'Sent Items' and 'Deleted Items' tabs, but my POP3 accounts do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to File > Account Settings > select the account & click on 'Change'. Click on 'More Settings' then 'Sent Items' tab. Then change from 'Save sent items in the following folder on the server', to 'Save sent items in the sent items folder on this computer... Davsmg

Answer (score 4):

You are much better off just disabling automatic saving of messages in the Sent Items folder and then creating a rule that stores a copy of all sent email in the desired folder.

1. File - Options - Mail - Save Messages
   Un-check the "Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder"
2. File - Manage Rules and Alerts - Apply Rule on Messages I send
   2.1 Don't check anything on the first screen
   2.2 Check "move a copy to the specified folder"
   2.3 Click on "specified" (at the bottom) and select the folder
   2.4 Finish the rule

Voila! All your sent items are now saved to the specified folder. Note that this won't apply to messages you send on other clients (such as a mobile or web client).

Comment: Nice workaround, this should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume Outlook Data is a .pst file?

In 2007:

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Mail Setup -> Data Files`. You can choose the default folder there.

In 2010:

Go to `File -> Account Settings -> Data Files tab`. You can choose the default folder there.

Comment: are you saying on outlook 2010?

Comment: @Achu Sorry, I edited the post. I forgot it was moved from the Tools menu in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Be CAREFUL, especially in Outlook 2010, because if you are connecting to an Exchange Server (MS Exchange 2010 for me) then you will see a WARNING that says changing the default folders (Inbox or Sent Items) will result in storing your email ONLY on your local PC.  Whether this is absolutely the case, or not, I would not risk it (unless you have control of the exchange server and can do what you want... but then you probably would not be reading this!)

A BETTER SOLUTION for Outlook 2010:  I found this excellent article on goovyPost http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/how-to-automatically-bcc-in-outlook-2010/ that explains how to set up Outlook 2010 to blind copy (BCC) yourself on all of your emails.  You will have to do this first if you want to then use rules...

Once you set up automatic BCC, you can then set up Outlook rules for incoming messages to go where-ever you want them.  One quick method guide is here http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2012/04/23/quick-rule-creation-in-outlook-2010.aspx, and you can just search Google for many other sites that tell you how.

I hope this helps you as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File → Account Settings
2. In the E-mail tab click "Change Folder Option"
3. Click Yes
4. Select the required option and click OK
5. Restart Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Each time I send e-mail I want to save the sent mail to either the default "sent mail" folder, or be able to select the folder manually from a drop-down of available folders under my inbox (this makes it much easier to manage sent mail).

I have set up my inbox "view" tab using "Conversations", and a few weeks back all "sent" mail showed as part of the thread "conversations", this was working rather nicely but for some unknown reason it stopped working?  Go figure ??

Comment: Could you edit this to make more clear how someone would make the change to Outlook - even if they can live with your side effect of messing up conversation threads.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer of Davsmg does not work under all circumstances. For example, my default account is Windows Live Hotmail, and Outlook does not let you change any of it's folder settings.

An alternative would be to use a rule to move the messages, once they are sent. However, Outlook rules for sent items only support copy actions (not move) and after copying the messages to another folder, they have the unread status. This leaves you in a situation where you have two copies of your sent items, and in the target folder they are all unread. Not what I want.

Not wanting to develop a complex VBA script for such a seemingly simple task, I used the AutoArchive feature of Outlook to move all sent items to a folder of my choice. The only drawback is that you can't archive more often than once per day and you can't archive items younger than one day. If you can live with day old sent items in the default folder and all other sent items (marked as read) in the folder of your choice, then this solution might work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Change, move or rename the default folder using this tool: https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com

as demonstrated here:
http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/renamedefaultfolders.htm