# How to change the folder Outlook 2010 saves sent emails to?

Tags: windows, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010

How to change the folder Outlook 2010 saves sent emails to? I want a custom one, because I want to use my account from two different clients - Outlook 2010 and Thunderbird.

Comment: Is your Outlook running in Exchange mode or standalone?

Comment: I am working with my company's Exchange server.

Comment: @CharlieRB: He is using IMAP (he commented that on a deleted answer), so no Exchange Mode.

Comment: On Thunderbird I use IMAP, on Outlook 2010 I can see "Connected to Microsoft Exchange" status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules on outgoing messages always run client-side, never on the server, so you are looking at two separate solutions for the Outlook 2010 and Thunderbird clients.

You will need to create rules in both mail-clients that will forward a copy of all outgoing mail to the new Saved-Sent folder, which will probably also require a server-side rule to get these forwards to the right folder.

For Thunderbird, maybe the [Send Filter add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/addon/send-filter/) can help.
For outlook, [Create a rule to file our outgoing emails](http://realestate.about.com/od/softwareandservices/ss/transact_rules_3.htm) might help.

<sub>(As I don't use Exchange or Outlook, I can't help with the details.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

See [How can I change my default inbox and sent folders in Outlook 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/260306/how-can-i-change-my-default-inbox-and-sent-folders-in-outlook-2010)

You can also change the location per message. In a mail message on the ribbon, click Options -> Save Sent Items To -> Another folder

Comment: I can't see any solution at this link. I do not want to change it for one email. I want to change the default.

Comment: From the link: "In 2010: Go to File -> Account Settings -> Data Files tab. You can choose the default folder there."